# rowsums for matrix over randomly specified subsets of columns in R

Tags: r

I have this matrix

```
mu<-1:100
sigma<-100:1
sample.size<-10
toy.mat<-mapply(function(x,y){rnorm(x,y,n=sample.size)},x=mu,y=sigma)
colnames(toy.mat) <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10), rep(3,10), rep(4,10), rep(5,10), 
                      rep(6,10), rep(7,10), rep(8,10), rep(9,10), rep(10,10) )
```

For the 10 columns named (1) I like to randomly select 5 pairs and rowsums each pair to  generate 5 columns named (1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 1e). I will do the same with columns named 2, 3 to 10.
Is there a data.table method to do this?

Comment: Five pairs of values within the columns? Do the pairs need to come from separate columns or can both pairs come from the same column? Is there a reason that your newly generated columns must be a column? This kind of problem would probably be better suited for a keyed long-form data.table, e.g. data.table(melt(toy.mat))

Comment: I want to rowsums across randomly selected columns and generate in new column with the results

Comment: I'm still confused as to what the pairs are? Also not sure if you want row sums of the pairs (i.e. sums of two elements) or sums of the rows of colnames where column=1?

Comment: I am aware that you want to focus on the 10 columns named (1), but I am still confused as to: (a) What are your pairs? (b) By extension of the pairs, the rowsums you want? Currently, I am thinking how do a pair and rowsums actually make up your desired 5 columns each with assumingly 10 elements

Comment: Agree with @MBorg; can you edit your question to give an actual random example of these "5 pairs" from the 10 columns names (1)?

Comment: Take for example `set.seed(2017); replicate(5, sample(10, 2))`. This generates 5 pairs of two numbers drawn from the sequence `1:10`. In this case, you can end up with the same pair. Is this what you are referring to when you talk about "randomly select[ing] 5 pairs"?

Comment: let's focus in the 10 columns named "1". I create a vector call names: `names=c(1a, 1c, 1a, 1b, 1d, 1c, 1d, 1b, 1e, 1e)`, like the order of elements in names is random. Then: `colnames(toy.mat)=names. Finally  `rowSums(toy.mat[,c('1a', '1a')])'. But I will like to do this all at ones in the whole matrix with all the columns.

Comment: @ALejandro Don't put clarifications in comments. Please edit and update your original post!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure about what you're trying to do.

This is what I understood.

1. I first split `toy.mat` into a `list` of 10 matrices (chunks). This is for convenience.

   ```
   # Split toy.mat into list of matrices
   lst <- lapply(seq(1, 100, by = 10), function(i) toy.mat[, i:(i+9)]);
   ```
2. Next, generate 5 random pairs, by sampling 10 numbers from the sequence `1:10` and coercing them into a `5x2` matrix. Repeat for all 10 matrix chunks.

   ```
   # Generate 5 random pairs
   set.seed(2017);   # For reproducibility of results
   rand <- replicate(10, matrix(sample(1:10, 10), ncol = 5), simplify = FALSE);
   head(rand, n = 2);
   #[[1]]
   #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
   #[1,]   10    4    9    1    6
   #[2,]    5    3    8    2    7
   #
   #[[2]]
   #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
   #[1,]    7    9    3    5   10
   #[2,]    1    4    2    6    8
   ```
3. Select corresponding columns based on pairs from `rand` and calculate the `rowSums`. Do that for every matrix chunk.

   ```
   # Select column pairs and calculate rowSums
   lst.rand <- lapply(1:10, function(i)
       sapply(as.data.frame(rand[[i]]), function(w) rowSums(lst[[i]][, w])));
   ```
4. Bind `list` elements into `matrix`, and set column names.

   ```
   # Bind into
   mat <- do.call(cbind, lst.rand);
   colnames(mat) <- as.vector(sapply(1:10, function(i) paste0(i, letters[1:5])));
   mat[1:5, 1:6];
   #             1a         1b          1c         1d         1e        2a
   #[1,]  21.410826   34.90337  -11.297396  -50.56332 -115.82456  51.32369
   #[2,]   5.323713 -144.26640  169.697538  -58.35540   96.25637 -78.95717
   #[3,] -78.925937  -45.32790 -177.546469  251.69348  -52.85132 123.38741
   #[4,] -33.673704  -95.64937    3.561921 -253.95046 -136.88182 -10.20650
   #[5,]  51.080564 -180.87033 -161.861342  108.41120  188.07454  52.34226
   ```